# Заимствования на "-оль"

Tags: заимствования

Какого рода химико-фармакологические заимствования заканчивающиеся на "-оль" (люголь, левомиколь, канифоль) - женского рода, мужского или когда как?

Answer (score 1):

Неправда ваша. *Люголь* - мужского рода, *канифоль* - женского, *левомЕколь* - узкоспециальный термин, в общеязыковых словарях его нет. Например, *гликоль*, *пергидроль* - мужского рода. (Полный орфографический словарь русского языка под ред. В.В.Лопатина).

Кстати, нашла латинское название этой мази *левомЕколь* - лат. Laevomecolum. Судя по окончанию, в латинском языке это слово среднего рода. В русском же слова, заканчивающиеся на мягкий знак, не могут быть среднего рода. Поскольку речь идет о мази, я склоняюсь к женскому роду. Но утверждать не берусь. В контекстах, попавшихся мне на глаза, название препарата всегда используется в качестве несогласованного приложения при определяемом слове *мазь*: *пользоваться мазью "Левомеколь", речь идет о мази "Левомеколь"* и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще нужно заглядывать в словарик.

По ощущениями, *левомеколь* - мужского рода (*намазался левомеколем*, *применение левомеколя* и т.д.). *Канифоль* - 100% женского рода. *Люголь* - такое ощущение, что мужского.

Answer (score 0):

Однако у 3 пациентов в 1-е сутки лечения отмечалось чувство жжения в области повязки, что заставило нас продолжить лечение Левомеколем. 
http://www.consilium-medicum.com/magazines/special/article/6639

Comment: Если не трудно, пишите чуть подробнее. Не ограничивайтесь одной цитатой.

Answer (score -1):

Химико-фармакологические заимствования на -"оль" женского рода